# Check if Go type shadows/implements one function of an embedded type's interface

Tags: go, interface, embedding, shadowing

```
type A interface {
  MyFunc()
}

type A struct {
}

func (a *A) MyFunc() {...}
 
type B struct {
  *A
}
var _ A = &B{}
var _ A = (*B)(nil)
```

B implements interface A because of the embedded A. So far, so good.

But how can I check (statically or at runtime) that B implements its own version of `MyFunc`?

UPDATE: There is no way to check this statically at compile time.

```
func (b *B) MyFunc() {...}
var _ ??? = &B{}
var _ ??? = (*B)(nil)
```

Comment: The method set determines if an interface is implemented, and the `B` method set contains a `MyFunc()` in both cases. Defining a different `MyFunc()` does not change the method set.

Comment: I don't understand how that relates to my question. I know that the method set determines the interface. I want to check if it's full-filled because of embedding A or being full-filled by B (like when A wasn't embedded).

Use-Case: A implements a standard behavior, and now I want to check that B overrides this standard behavior with its own implementation.

Comment: It's related because your example is trying to assert the condition using the type system at compile time, and the type system does not have a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

*tl;dr* You can't, for the reason @JimB mentioned.

---

To respond to your most recent comment:
*"I just want to ensure that users of a framework get some hints about how to best used the interfaces."*

If my goal were to suggest best practices to my users, I would just document it somewhere. Yes, there's this myth that nobody reads documentation ever, but anyway if you allow `B` to be composed with `A`, the semantics of your design are precisely "B can have A's behavior". So the point of warning your users about this is kinda moot. It's like you gave your customer a hammer and said "keep in mind, this is a B-type hammer". Well, still a hammer it is. If you want to bestow your customers with nail-hitting capabilities, where they got the hammer from, and any associated warning, is beside the point.

---

As for the technicalities:

The method set of a type is all what the compiler needs to determine if the type satisfies an interface. How the methods got there is irrelevant.

Unfortunately the Go specs isn't supremely straightforward about this point, but it's possible to piece together an explanation.

> A field or method `f` of an embedded field in a struct `x` is called promoted if `x.f` is a legal selector that denotes that field or method `f`.

The legal selector:

> A selector `f` may denote a field or method `f` of a type T, or it may refer to a field or method `f` of a nested embedded field of `T`

So is `b.Myfunc` a legal selector? Yes, because it refers to a method of the embedded struct. Such method is called *promoted*. Then:

> Given a struct type `S` and a defined type `T`, promoted methods are included in the method set of the struct [...goes on describing rules for embedding `T` vs `*T`]

Finally:

> The method set of a type determines the interfaces that the type implements

That's all you can get from the specs. No mention is made about why or how a method is included in a method set *for the purposes of satisfying interfaces*.

The only additional piece of information now is that when `B` does have `MyFunc` in its method set both directly and via embedding `A`, if you call `b.MyFunc`, `B`'s implementation runs due to the *depth* rule which is a formal way to, substantially, define a behavior similar to what in OOP is overriding: a selector `x.f` denotes `f` at the shallowest depth, and when `f` results from embedding a type `A`, its depth is its depth in `A`+1, whereas the method declared directly has depth 0.